# Extract the values from the url using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

What I'm trying to do is extract the values from html tag  ul, li, span  the following url:
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/11/23/israel-new-laws_n_6207042.html#comments
from the URl i want to get **Number of comments count** and ***Number of share count***

Example:

```
<ul class="shares group">
<li class="share facebook_like VERB_LIKE" data-type="f blike">
<a href="http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/11/23/israel-new-laws_n_6207042.html" data- send="false" data-layout="box_coun</span></div>  </a></li><li class="share facebook" data-type="facebook">

 <a class="social-fb-share-btn"data-title="Israel Mulls Hard-Line Legislation After    Attacks">
  <span class="facebook-share-btn label">Share</span>
  <span class="facebook-share-count count" data-count="283">283</span>
</a>    
</li> 
   <li class="share twitter" data-type="twitter">
<div class="social-twitter-btn" data-size="71" data-account="theworldpost">
<a class="twitter-tweet-btn" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?  lang=en&amp;text=Israel+Mulls+Hard-  Line+Legislation+After+Attacks+http%3A%2F%2Fhuff.to%2F1rdclw6" sl-processed="1">
  <span class="twitter-tweet-btn label">Tweet</span>
   <span class="twitter-tweet-count count" data-count="103">103</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: So, I assume you haven't been able to select the HTML content for `facebook-share-count` and process the contents of the node? You will receive more help if you provide your code so far.

Comment: I believe those numbers are generated by javascript. Jsoup can't handle that. You have to use a headless browser. Check selenium or HtmlUnit